# Calculating temperature from multi-spectral map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, measurements, rgb, land-surface-temperature

I have a map showing heat islands in a large city in the form of a multispectral (RGB) raster. I'd like to obtain the temperature or at least a temperature scale (the ultimate idea is to be able to measure the differences in heat between two zones according to a scale but not necessarily in exact temperature).

I'm new to QGIS.

Is it possible to calculate this from my map and how?

I tried to retrieve the red, blue and green bands and extracted the results using the statistical tools, but the hottest areas are classified as less hot than moderately hot areas.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's a multi spectral image, it's a picture of some temperature data, you'll need to find the data used to make the picture if you want to measure things

Comment: What is the data source?

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for your reply.  I'm trying to find it but Environnement.brussels ()https://data.gov.be/fr/dataset/73b4f29a-cff0-4d6a-a239-cb99d3140531) only makes this available...

Comment: @HyPhens These data come from Environnement.brussels: https://data.gov.be/fr/dataset/73b4f29a-cff0-4d6a-a239-cb99d3140531

Comment: @SimGeographer It looks like a georeferenced RGB image; you could do a sort of remapping and maybe find the pixels from the hottest and coolest areas, but I think it would be very difficult (impossible) to get a coherent temperature scale if you do not obtain the raw data used to create the image or an image with a temperature band. I would suggest to ask the data provider/organization if they can send this kind of data.